# When installing PySDD, I receive "ERROR: Failed building wheel for PySDD"

Tags: python, pip

So, I was running this jupyter notebook when I received the following error:
`InstallError: The SDD library is not available. Please install the PySDD package..`

Then I tried to install PySDD using the instructions given [here](https://pysdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/installation.html) . I started with `pip install pysdd` and received a huge error message on the command prompt, containing   `ERROR: Failed building wheel for PySDD` and   `Running setup.py clean for pysdd Failed to build pysdd Installing collected packages: pysdd Running setup.py install for pysdd ... error`. I also tried `pip install -vvv --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps pysdd`  but that didn't help either.

Also, as it suggests [here](https://github.com/wannesm/PySDD#dependencies), I have Cython installed as well.
I'd appreciate any help or hint. Thanks.

Edit: As suggested in the comments, this is the output to `pip install -vvv pysdd` :

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysdd
  Running setup.py clean for pysdd
  Running command 'c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4k4__tdk\\pysdd\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4k4__tdk\\pysdd\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
  cysignals not found
  No module named 'cysignals'
  running clean
  removing 'build\lib.win-amd64-3.8' (and everything under it)
  'build\bdist.win-amd64' does not exist -- can't clean it
  'build\scripts-3.8' does not exist -- can't clean it
  removing 'build'
Failed to build pysdd
Installing collected packages: pysdd
  Created temporary directory: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ii5gatby
    Running command 'c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4k4__tdk\\pysdd\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4k4__tdk\\pysdd\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ii5gatby\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pysdd'
    cysignals not found
    No module named 'cysignals'
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\cli.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\iterator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\util.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\wmcstochastic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\__main__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    running egg_info
    writing PySDD.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to PySDD.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to PySDD.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to PySDD.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to PySDD.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'PySDD.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'PySDD.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying pysdd\compiler_c.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\fnf_c.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\io_c.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\sdd.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\sdd.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    copying pysdd\sddapi_c.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\sddapi.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\build
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\build\libsdd.a -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\debug
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\debug\libsdd.a -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\debug
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include\iterators.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include\macros.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include\parameters.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include\sdd.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include\stacks.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\include
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\util.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\verify.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\version.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\computed.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\count_and_size.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\gc.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\hash.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\memory.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\multiply.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\nodes.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\partitions.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\references.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\replace.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\shadows.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic\sort.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\basic
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\fnf
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\fnf\io.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\fnf
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager\copy.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager\interface.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager\manager.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager\stats.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager\variables.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\manager
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\apply.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\bits.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\cardinality.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\condition.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\copy.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\count.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\essential_vars.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\exists.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\exists_multiple.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\exists_multiple_static.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\forall.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\io.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\model_count.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\rename_vars.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\size.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds\wmc.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\sdds
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_fragments
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_fragments\construction.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_fragments
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_fragments\moves.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_fragments
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_fragments\operations.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_fragments
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations\cartesian_product.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations\dissect.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations\limits.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations\op_left_rotate.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations\op_right_rotate.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations\op_swap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations\rollback.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations\split.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations\vtree_ops.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_operations
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_search
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_search\auto.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_search
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_search\search.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_search
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_search\state.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtree_search
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees\compare.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees\edit.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees\io.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees\maps.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees\moves.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees\static.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees
    copying pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees\vtree.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\libsdd-2.0\src\vtrees
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src\circuit-gc.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src\circuit.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src\test-1.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src\test-2.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src\test-3.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src\test-4.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src\test-5.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\examples\src
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\include
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\include\compiler.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\include
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\include\fnf.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\include
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\include\io.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\include
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\include\sddapi.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\include
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Darwin
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Darwin\libsdd.a -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Darwin
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Darwin\debug
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Darwin\debug\libsdd.a -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Darwin\debug
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Linux
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Linux\libsdd.a -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Linux
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Linux\libsdd.so -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Linux
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Windows
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Windows\libsdd.a -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\lib\Windows
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\getopt.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\main.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\fnf
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\fnf\compiler.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\fnf
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\fnf\fnf.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\fnf
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\fnf\io.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\fnf
    copying pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\fnf\utils.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pysdd\lib\sdd-2.0\src\fnf
    running build_ext
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4k4__tdk\pysdd\setup.py", line 181, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 79, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 186, in run
        _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
      File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4k4__tdk\pysdd\setup.py", line 107, in build_extensions
        compiler_name = self.compiler.compiler[0]
    AttributeError: 'MSVCCompiler' object has no attribute 'compiler'
    Compiler type: msvc
    Running setup.py install for pysdd ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4k4__tdk\\pysdd\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4k4__tdk\\pysdd\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ii5gatby\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pysdd' Check the logs for full command output.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 838, in install
    success = install_legacy(
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\legacy.py", line 86, in install
    raise LegacyInstallFailure
pip._internal.operations.install.legacy.LegacyInstallFailure

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 228, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 182, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 397, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 82, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 856, in install
    six.reraise(*exc.parent)
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\legacy.py", line 74, in install
    runner(
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 273, in runner
    call_subprocess(
  File "c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4k4__tdk\\pysdd\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4k4__tdk\\pysdd\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ii5gatby\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pysdd' Check the logs for full command output.
Removed build tracker: 'C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-tracker-9oiecj10'
```

Comment: Per the [installation instructions](https://pysdd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/installation.html): do you have [SDD package](http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/sdd/)? PySDD is only a Python wrapper for SDD so you have to have SDD installed.

Comment: Also please show the full text of output of `pip install -vvv pysdd`

Comment: Thanks. I added the error message I receive when trying your suggestion. Also, as for the SDD package, I tried ```pip install SDD```. Did not solve the problem.

Comment: Now I am not sure if ```pip install SDD ``` is what I need. [Here](https://pypi.org/project/SDD/) where ```pip install SDD ``` is recommended, SDD stands for Social Distance, while the SDD in pySDD stands for Sequential Decision Diagrams.

Comment: `pip install SDD` is **certainly not what you want**. It installs a **Python package SDD** while you need [C package SDD](http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/sdd/download.php).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now it seems that the entire problem boils down to the wrong OS: this SDD package is only for Linux or MAC, as another comment suggested earlier. Is there any way I can have it on Windows 10?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, never worked with SDD or w32.

Answer (score -1):

Try to update pip version : pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I got: "Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (20.2.4)", and still get the same error when installing PySDD.

Comment: it might be your operation system. I am not sure it can run on windows. when I tried to install it on windows it fails but on linux (using docker) it was installed smoothly. I saw in SSD documentation that it runs only on Linux and Mac